# How to display all post from the same current usermeta

Tags: customization, users, user-registration

When someone register to my site, they must fill this field (as user meta data) :

- Name : A
- Country: B
- Region: C

so.. when I or other author was log in , I need a link that will display all post from the people who have same country & region with me ..  how I can do that?

P.S : 
I build my registration form with "ultimate member" plug in

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have time to write the code, but here's what you need to do essentially:

- Get the current author ID
- Get the country-field for that user ID. Save this in a `$variable`.
- In the loop, before the HTML output code, get the author ID and then get the country-field for that user ID. Store this in $variable2.
- Then, wrap the HTML output code in an if-statement where you check if $variable === $variable2.

That is essentially how you do it. If no one else has later on, I will write some code for you, but right now I don't have time.

Comment: @awangfaisal So do I need to write the code or not?